# Terraform Azurerm azurerm_shared_image_version data not reading latest version of image

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating VM using Ubuntu based custom image from Azure Compute Gallery. Following is the data block that I'm using to get latest image version and update the VM.

```
data "azurerm_shared_image_version" "stg_linux_image" {
  name                = "latest"
  image_name          = "my-ubuntu-image"
  gallery_name        = "my_custom_gallery"
  resource_group_name = "my_pe_rg"
}
```

Till yesterday, it was reading the correct version. I'm using `$(Build.BuildId)` to create image version names. The version names were like:

- 1.0.99549
- 1.0.99690

But yesterday the build id became six digits and the image version name is:

- 1.0.100150

After this, unless I specify `1.0.100150`, the data block is reading `1.0.99690` with `latest` tag.

What am I doing wrong or is there a limitation on name length which I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some digging. `TF_LOG_PROVIDER=trace` helped me.
The provider is reading all the image versions. But unfortunately when sorting to get latest version looks like it is picking images with version starting with 9xxx over 1xxx as 9 comes after 1. It is ignoring the fact that the one with 1xxxx has 6 digits but 9xxxx has  only 5.

To handle, I've changed versioning scheme to `yyMMdd.HHmm.ss`